# where is the docker image stored in gitlab ci?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, trivy

I have build a docker image successfully and tag it as `testdock:latest` ($CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest) the $CI_REGISTRY variable is kept in GitLab project variable.

I have another stage , to start scanning the `testdock` image by using `Trivy`:
the process is just stuck without progress. I am guessing is that the image cannot be found  or something wrong with the docker environment in GitLab.

```
   Where is the `docker image (testdock)` stored?
```

this is the command that I used for `Trivy` to scan the `testdock` image:

```
$ TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy --skip-update --output "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/scanning-report.json"  $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

the yml:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/devops/docker:latest
  services:
    - $CI_REGISTRY/devops/docker:dind-nx1.0
  #tags:
  #  - docker
  variables:
    # No need to clone the repo, we exclusively work on artifacts.  See
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#git-strategy
    TRIVY_USERNAME: "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"
    TRIVY_PASSWORD: "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
    TRIVY_AUTH_URL: "$CI_REGISTRY"
    FULL_IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    # Tell docker CLI how to talk to Docker daemon.
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
    # Use the overlayfs driver for improved performance.
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    # Disable TLS since we're running inside local network.
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build -t $FULL_IMAGE_NAME  .
   # - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest

security_scan:
  stage: test
  image: 
    name: $CI_REGISTRY/devops/trivy/trivy:0.20.1
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - $CI_REGISTRY/devops/docker:dind-nx1.0
  #tags:
   # - docker
  variables:
    # No need to clone the repo, we exclusively work on artifacts.  See
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#git-strategy
  #  GIT_STRATEGY: none
    TRIVY_USERNAME: "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"
    TRIVY_PASSWORD: "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
    TRIVY_AUTH_URL: "$CI_REGISTRY"
    FULL_IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    # Tell docker CLI how to talk to Docker daemon.
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
    # Use the overlayfs driver for improved performance.
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    # Disable TLS since we're running inside local network.
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  before_script:
    - git config --global http.sslVerify false
    - git clone $CI_REPOSITORY_URL
    - echo "the project directory is - $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - echo "the CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE variable is - $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
    - echo "the full image name is - $FULL_IMAGE_NAME"
    - ls -la
    - trivy -h | grep cache
    - mkdir -p /root/.cache/trivy/db
    - ls -la
    - cp "eval-trivy-2/trivy-offline.db.tgz" "/root/.cache/trivy/db"
    - cd /root/.cache/trivy/db
    - tar xvf trivy-offline.db.tgz
    - ls -la
  script:
    - trivy --version
    - time trivy image --clear-cache
    # running 1 hr and stopped.
    #- TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy --skip-update $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    #- TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy --skip-update -f json -o scanning-report.json $CI_REGISTRY/devops/aquasec/trivy:0.16.0
    - TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy --skip-update -o "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/scanning-report.json" $FULL_IMAGE_NAME
    #keep loading by using testdock:latest
    #- TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy --skip-update -o "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/scanning-report.json"  testdock:latest
   # - TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy --skip-update --exit-code 1 --severity CRITICAL $CI_REGISTRY/devops/aquasec/trivy:0.16.0
  artifacts:
    when:                          always
    reports:
      container_scanning:          scanning-report.json
```

Answer (score 1):

All jobs are running isolated. Therefore `jobA` normally does not know what `jobB` produced as long as you do not tell the job specifically to pass things on to the next job with the `artifacts` directive.

In your case you build your image in your job, but if you did not push it - it will be just like any throw away data and lost at the next stage. The easiest way is to push it to a docker registry and use it from there. eg. a common practice is to tag it with the commit SHA instead of latest. This way you can ensure you are always hitting the right image.

Comment: can you give me sample the best practise how to do it? i update the full yml at main post.

Comment: i change it to use $ TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy --skip-update -o "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/scanning-report.json" "$FULL_IMAGE_NAME" , still the process loading non-stop.

Answer (score 0):

final gitlan-ci.yml which works well now:

```
variables:
  # Tell docker CLI how to talk to Docker daemon.
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
  # Use the overlayfs driver for improved performance.
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  # Disable TLS since we're running inside local network.
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""


services:
  - $CI_REGISTRY/devops/docker:dind-nx1.0

stages:
  - build
  - test

#include:
  # Trivy integration with GitLab Container Scanning
 # - remote: "https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/raw/master/contrib/Trivy.gitlab-ci.yml"

build:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/devops/docker:latest
  stage: build
  variables:
    IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  script:
    - docker info
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $IMAGE .
    - docker tag $IMAGE $CI_REGISTRY/$IMAGE
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/$IMAGE 

Trivy_container_scanning:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: $CI_REGISTRY/devops/trivy/trivy:0.20.1
  variables:
    # Override the GIT_STRATEGY variable in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and set it to `fetch` if you want to provide a `clair-whitelist.yml`
    # file. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/container_scanning/index.html#overriding-the-container-scanning-template
    # for details
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    IMAGE: "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - trivy image --reset
    - git config --global http.sslVerify false
    - git clone $CI_REPOSITORY_URL
    - echo "the project directory is - $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - echo "the registry image is - $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
    - ls -la
    - trivy -h | grep cache
    - mkdir -p /root/.cache/trivy/db
    - ls -la
    - cp "eval-trivy-4/trivy-offline.db.tgz" "/root/.cache/trivy/db"
    - cd /root/.cache/trivy/db
    - tar xvf trivy-offline.db.tgz
    - ls -la
    #- export TRIVY_VERSION=${TRIVY_VERSION:-v0.19.2}
    #- apk add --no-cache curl docker-cli
    #- docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    #- curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aquasecurity/trivy/main/contrib/install.sh | sh -s -- -b /usr/local/bin ${TRIVY_VERSION}
    #- curl -sSL -o /tmp/trivy-gitlab.tpl https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/raw/${TRIVY_VERSION}/contrib/gitlab.tpl
  script:
    - TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy image --skip-update -f json -o "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/gl-container-scanning-report.json" $CI_REGISTRY/$IMAGE
  #unable to write results: failed to initialize template writer: error retrieving template from path: open /tmp/trivy-gitlab.tpl: no such file or directory
   # - TRIVY_INSECURE=true trivy image --skip-update --format template --template "@/tmp/trivy-gitlab.tpl" -o gl-container-scanning-report.json $CI_REGISTRY/$IMAGE
    #scan error
    #- trivy --skip-update --format template --template "@/tmp/trivy-gitlab.tpl" -o gl-container-scanning-report.json $CI_REGISTRY/$IMAGE
    #- trivy --exit-code 0 --cache-dir .trivycache/ --no-progress --format template --template "@/tmp/trivy-gitlab.tpl" -o gl-container-scanning-report.json $IMAGE
 # cache:
  #  paths:
 #     - .trivycache/
  artifacts:
    reports:
      container_scanning: gl-container-scanning-report.json
```

reference and modified for my env

```
https://gitlab.com/aquasecurity/trivy-ci-test/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml
```